# Solving damped mass-spring system with changing External Force

Tags: differential-equations

For $m \ddot x+b\dot x+kx=F$,where $m,b,k$ is given.

When $F$ is a constant, I know I can do:

```
Eqn=m*x''[t]+b*x'[t]+k*x[t]=F
sol=NDSolveValue[{Eqn,x[0]==0,x'[t]==0},x[t],{t,0,1}]
Plot[Evaluate[sol],{t,0,1}]
```

If I want to make a 3D plot of $x,F,t$.
Where $F=f sin(wt)$, $f$ is not a constant, it has value from 0 to 10, $w$ is a known value. What should I do?

I have tried:

```
NDSolveValue[{m*D[x[t,f],{t,2}+b*D[x[t,f],t]+k*x[t,f]==f*Sin[w*t]},x[t,f],{t,f}]
```

I tried to give inital value, range, but it still won't work.

Comment: Look for `ParametricNDSolve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use numerical solver on this, as it is easy to solve analytically and you can manipulate all the parameters

[image]

```
ClearAll[m, x, t, b, k, f, w];
ode = m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + k*x[t] == f*Cos[w *t];
ic = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0};
sol = x[t] /. First@DSolve[{ode, ic}, x[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[sol /. {f -> f0, b -> b0, m -> m0, k -> k0, w -> w0}, {t, 0, 
   tmax}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10, 10}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray],
 {{m0, 5, "mass?"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k0, .1, "stiffness?"}, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b0, .1, "Damping?"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f0, .3, "f?"}, .1, .5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{w0, .01, "forcing frequency?"}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tmax, 150, "max time?"}, 1, 200, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tmax, f0, b0, m0, k0, w0}
 ]
```

You had some errors. You can't use `x'[t]==0` as initial conditions.

You can adjust the sliders ranges as needed.

ps. Wolfram Demonstration site has a demo to study such a system also with more options:

[DynamicAnalysisOfASecondOrderSystemWithHarmonicLoading](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DynamicAnalysisOfASecondOrderSystemWithHarmonicLoading/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!